# Multiple SQL querys in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, nodes

how would i make multiple MySQL querys in NodeJS, in the following code `con = mysql.createConnection(...)`

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM BRUGERE WHERE username = ${username}`, function(err, data) {
    console.log("Username in use");
});

console.log("Query Done");

con.query(`INSERT INTO users(username, password, salt, token) VALUES(${username}, ${password}, ${salt}, ${token});`, function(err, data) {
    console.log("Success");
});
```

The output of this code is "Query Done" but it never gets down to console.log "Success" and it didn't insert anything to the database.

Comment: Instead of only attempting to print "Success", have you tried to print out "err"? console.log(err), to see if there's an error being thrown. Alternatively you can use try catch blocks

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap both of these queries in promises to help get what you are trying to achieve.

```js
const query1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM BRUGERE WHERE username = ${username}`, function(err, data) {
        console.log("Username in use");
        resolve(true)
    });
})

await query1;
console.log("Query Done");

const query2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(`INSERT INTO users(username, password, salt, token) VALUES(${username}, ${password}, ${salt}, ${token});`, function(err, data) {
        console.log("Success");
        resolve(true)
    })
})

await query2;
```